# How to highlight/focus two EditTexts in Android?

Tags: android

I have two EditTexts in an activity. I am trying to implement it so that when one EditText is focused, the second one looks like it is focused too (the underline must be bold as it is when EditText is focused).

I am trying to change underline like this when focus changes:

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
              if (!hasFocus) {
                 // here editText2 must have not state
              } else {
                 // here editText2 must have not state
              }
          }
      });
```

But how can I make the underline bold on another text without it actually receiving focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                  if (!hasFocus) {
                       editText2.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL);

                  } else {
                       editText2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); 
                  }
              }
          });
```

Comment: thank you. but this also changes the font of edittext

Comment: Then also set the font which you want in the if condition